# Create folder next to INSTALLFOLDER

Tags: c#, wix

In my setup Wix, I want to create a folder next to INSTALLFOLDER, to copy a pdf with user manual.

This is what I want :

```
- Program Files
|- ApplicationINSTALL
    |- application.exe
|- ApplicationREADME
    |- user_manual.pdf
```

Actually my code is :

```
<Fragment>
    <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="$(var.product)">
            <!-- some sub folders -->
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
</Fragment>
```

**My setup allows user to change `INSTALLFOLDER`, so I can't just define my directory in ProgramFilesFolder.**

How can I write my code to be sure to have `READMEFOLER` next to `INSTALLFOLDER` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
<Fragment>
    <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="$(var.product)">
            <Directory Id="APPFOLDER" Name="App">
                <Component Id="APPEXE">
                    <File Id="APPEXEfile" Source="bin\application.exe" />
            </Component>
            </Directory>
            <Directory Id="DOCFOLDER" Name="ReadMe" />
            <Component Id="README">
                <File Id="READMEfile" Source="doc\readme.pdf" />
            </Component>
            </Directory>
    </Directory>
</Directory>
```

Comment: This solution creates a folder more than I wanted but I've nothing better. I'll do like this.